# My question was downvoted without a reason

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes, community-moderation

[Does Fisher Information quantify only the precision of the instrument?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/491872/does-fisher-information-quantify-only-the-precision-of-the-instrument)

I had asked a question recently. There were some comments by someone named Solar Mike.

On repeatedly asking him/her on elaborating what he meant, there was no proper reply. I realized most of his answers are similar, on physics.stackexchange.

Comment: So what is your question? Downvoting without commenting is allowed on all Stackexchange sites. Nobody knows who downvoted except the person who did it. Speculating or accusing someone is not appropriate.

Comment: That's really an unfortunate mix up there. It seems Solar Mike thought you were asking about the information in Fisher's catalog (Fisher is a manufacturer of precision measurement instruments). If you read it in that way, then the question isn't very good, possibly explaining the downvote.

Comment: To help avoid this kind of mix up, it's useful to link to, e.g. Wikipedia on any terms that don't have an unambiguous definition.

Comment: I've added what I hope is a helpful link to clarify the question.

Comment: As Jon pointed out, it's not really clear what you're asking here. I've put the question on hold until that gets clarified.

Comment: @knzhou I think that could be a goof up. He had been insisting again and again on calibrating the instrument. I thought that Fisher Information is well known in the Physics community, looking at other questions on physics.stackexchange. I will include sources and definitions henceforth.